# Save a checkout custom field

Tags: php, magento-1.9, checkout

I'm currently working on a custom shipping method.

I added a custom select field under the shipping methods available but I don't know how to save it in the database.

My custom field :

```
<select name="delivery_timeslot" id="delivery_timeslot" title='.$this->__('Delivery Timeslot').' class="select">
    <option value="<?php echo $timeSlot->getStartTimestamp()?> stuff </option>
    //other <option>
</select>
```

I suppose that I will have to create a custom attribute in the order class (or in the shipment class maybe) but I don't know how to do it.

Does someone can help me ?

Thanks.

Edit 1 :

I managed to create a custom attribute and save it in the database.
I can access it (to fill it or retrieve it) and it's working.

Now, I created an observer which will trigger when the customer submits an order and I want to retrieve my field.

How to do it ?